# Is the weak quark mixing a consequence of electroweak symmetry breaking?

Tags: standard-model, higgs, symmetry-breaking, electroweak

Because of the CKM matrix, the quark doublets that are changed by $W^{+}$ and $W^{-}$ include a linear combination of quark flavours, instead of the pure quark flavours. I was wondering if, before Electroweak symmetry breaking, the $W^{1,2,3}$ bosons are actually acting within the pure flavours, e.g. within u-d instead of u-d'. Is the linear combination of d' a consequence of expressing $W^{+, -}$ as linear combinations of $W^{1,2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the mixing of the flavors is not a direct consequence of the mixing of the gauge fields! It is a consequence of the masses of the quarks being non-degenerate. When writing down the most general (in general flavor mixing!) Yukawa coupling of the left-handed fermion $SU(2)$-doublet and the right-handed fermion $SU(2)$-singlet to the Higgs $SU(2)$-doublet you arrive (after insertion of the usual parameterization of the Higgs-doublet in terms of zero-vev fields) at a non-diagonal mass-matrix for the fermions.
It is the change into the fermion-field basis that diagonalizes the mass matrix that mixes the "u-d'" fields into the "u-d" fields. Since the neutrinos are considered massless in the Standard Model (and thus mass-degenerate), the diagonalization in the lepton sector does not necessarily introduce flavor mixing in the lepton sector.

If you would introduce non-degenerate neutrino masses into the SM you would also introduce a flavor mixing matrix in the lepton sector that in general is non-diagonal.

Note that this also implies that if you consider the (down-type) quarks massless (an approximation that is/was used frequently) then in order to be consistent you also neglect the CKM-Matrix in calculations!

See e.g. "Gauge Theories of the Strong and Electroweak Interaction" by M. Böhm, A. Denner and H. Joos

Comment: thank you, but does this mean that ckm mixing (which has been experimentally observed) is not compatible with neutrino masses (also experimentally observed) according to standard model?

Comment: No, why should they? The mixing in the quark sector is completely independent from the mixing in the lepton sector (to which the neutrinos belong).

Comment: i see! so i rephrase: would the experimental evidence of neutrino masses, require also a mixing matrix for the leptons which the Standard Model does not include? (as all lepton weak eigenstates are the pure flavours is SM)

Comment: I think this is answered in my original answer, but yes if you would introduce non-degenerate neutrino masses into the SM you would also introduce a mixing matrix.

Comment: What is or isn't part of the SM is a fuzzy thing and is not a very important question. Some people exclude neutrino masses from the SM, some people inclide them. At this point we know there is lepton mixing in reality and that's all that matters.

Comment: @AlmostClueless so standard model is not compatible with experimental evidence in this regard? also, i heard that the ckm mixing is connected to cp violation. In your nice answer, could you tell me at what point does it play a role?

Comment: Well the SM describes practically every collider experiment extremely precise. Neutrino masses are a tiny effect, and thus not (yet) a real concern in collider experiments. But yes *in principle* the neutrino masses, and thus resulting lepton-flavor mixing, should be included. The CP-violating phase of the CKM Matrix is material for an extra question and I strongly suggest to consult standard material concerning that topic before.

Comment: @AlmostClueless my point was that this lepton-flavor mixing has not been experimentally measured yet, am I wrong?